# How to get a duration of 1 day with Rust chrono?

Tags: rust, duration, rust-chrono

I am dealing with some Rust code that works with durations of days but the implementation of `Duration::days(n)` is, per the documentation `n * 24 * 60 * 60` seconds, which isn't n days because not all days are `24 * 60 * 60` seconds.

This behaviour is well documented:

> `pub fn days(days: i64) -> Duration`
>
> Makes a new `Duration` with given number of days. Equivalent to
>   `Duration::seconds(days * 24 * 60 * 60)` with overflow checks. Panics
>   when the duration is out of bounds.

Is there a way with Rust Chrono to get a duration that is, strictly, 1 day rather than a number of seconds and is compatible with the `DateTime` types? Not all days are the same number of seconds. `seconds` and `days` are quite different units. If there were such a function then the following would always give a result that is the same time of day on the following day?

```
let start = Local.now();
let one_day_later = start + function_that_returns_a_duration_of_days(1);
```

Again, `Duration:days(1)` is not such a function because it returns `1 * 24 * 60 * 60` seconds, rather than **1 day**.

For example, with *TZ* set to *America/Denver* the following:

```
let start = Local.ymd(2019, 3, 10).and_hms(0, 0, 0);
println!("start: {}", start);
let end = Local.ymd(2019, 3, 11).and_hms(0, 0, 0);
println!("end: {}", end);
let elapsed_seconds = end.timestamp() - start.timestamp();
println!("elapsed_seconds: {}", elapsed_seconds);
let end2 = start + Duration::days(1);
println!("end2: {}", end2);
let elapsed_seconds2 = end2.timestamp() - start.timestamp();
println!("elapsed_seconds2: {}", elapsed_seconds2);
```

Returns:

```
start: 2019-03-10 00:00:00 -07:00
end: 2019-03-11 00:00:00 -06:00
elapsed_seconds: 82800
end2: 2019-03-11 01:00:00 -06:00
elapsed_seconds2: 86400
```

It adds **86400 seconds**, rather than **1 day**.

I can get the ***correct*** result with:

```
let one_day_later =
    (start.date() + Duration::days(1)).and_hms(start.hour(), start.minute(), start.second());
```

But I would prefer a function that returns a duration of days and in general would like to know more about Rust Chrono capabilities for handling durations. Does it have durations with units other than seconds? What about weeks, months and years, which also have variable numbers of seconds.

I should probably say that I don't know Rust, only having worked with it for a few days now and I haven't much read the source code. I did look at it, but find it difficult to understand due to my limited familiarity with the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Duration` is an amount of time. There is no amount of time that when added to an instant, always yields the same time on the next day, because as you have noticed, calendar days may have different amounts of time in them.

Not only years, weeks and days, but even hours and minutes do not always comprise the same amount of time ([Leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)). A `Duration` is an amount of time, not a "calendar unit". So no, a `Duration` is not capable of expressing an idea like "same time next week".

The easiest way to express "same time next day" is with the `succ` and `and_time` methods on `Date`:

```
let one_day_later = start.date().succ().and_time(start.time());
```

`and_time` will panic if the time does not exist on the new date.

Comment: Thank you very much. I hadn't seen the succ() or and_time() methods. The latter is much more succinct than .ymd().and_hms()

Comment: What if I really don’t care about leap seconds? Is there any library which will allow me to do calculations like `01h45m - 0h55m + 2h37m` with a result where a hour does not have more than 60 minutes?

Comment: @Philipp Sure, [you can do that calculation with only `Duration`s](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0c0b05f7ca5063db6c36c7dc41d61188). Calendar issues like daylight saving time and leap seconds only appear when converting between a *duration* of time like "three hours" and an *instant* of time like "three o'clock a.m. on March 8, 2020".

Comment: Does not seem to work; if I do something like `Duration::minutes(50).checked_add(Duration.minutes(30))`, I get a duration which has 80 minutes, and 1 hours. I expect 1 hour and 20 minutes: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d52f78c94bd114b245760dfea39a6e27)

Comment: @Philipp The `num_hours` and `num_minutes` methods on `Duration` return the total number of *whole* hours or minutes in the duration, so yes, a duration of 80 minutes contains 1 hour (or 4800 seconds, or 4800000 milliseconds, etc.). If you want 20 you'll need to do some math to subtract off the whole hours, like `(duration - Duration::hours(duration.num_hours())).num_minutes()`, or maybe just `duration.num_minutes() % 60`.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!